# Comment traduire « the players that hang to the port of the bitt » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, terminologie, formulation

Dans le dictionnaire Cotgrave on trouve la définition de [*babillons*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50509g/f83.item) :

> The players that [hang](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/hang) to the port of a [bit](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/bit)t.

Il s'agit d'un objet relié à la direction d'un [cheval](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/276015). Comment traduit-on la phrase/explique-t-on en quoi consiste l'objet à l'intérieur du système en question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La définition pourrait être :

> Les jouets accrochés au [canon](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canon) d'un [mors](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mors).

Le canon peut aussi s'appeler [embouchure](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/embouchure), c'est la partie du mors placée dans la bouche du cheval.

Bien sûr, cette définition est parfaitement incompréhensible pour quelqu'un qui ne connait pas le vocabulaire de l'équitation, encore plus à l'oral où l'on entendra *...au canon d'un mort*.

Pour lui expliquer de quoi il s'agit, je dirais :

> Les petits trucs accrochés à la partie intérieure du mors d'un cheval destinés à le distraire et le faire saliver.

Wikipedia propose cette définition de [jouet](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jouet):

> 6. (Équitation) Petite chaîne que l’on accroche à la brisure du canon qui forme l’embouchure dans le mors d’un cheval.